# Print preview the html table in php codeignator

Tags: php

I am Using PHP CodeIgniter 3 for my project and i want to show my html table in print preview mode but am not able to do that does anyone know?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried multiple options like creating new page without any css or jss or multiple option but was not able to get the wanted results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show a HTML table in page's print preview only.

This can do by using CSS `@media print` query.

```
.html-table{
   display : none
}
@media print {
   .html-table{
      display : block;
   }
}
```